# mysql count word per designation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have simple mysql table:

```
id  designation   
1   Senior1      
2   Senior1      
3   Senior2    
4   Junior1      
5   Junior2
```

What I'm trying to count the designation.

I have a sample query but it only counts the specific word.

```
SELECT

SUM(IF(designation   = "Senior1", 1,0)) AS `Senior_total`,
SUM(IF(designation   = "Junior1", 1,0)) AS `Junior_total`

From mytable
```

as a result, I have.

```
Senior_total   Junior_total
2               1
```

I was looking for the output would be like this.

```
Senior_total   Junior_total
3               2
```

I was thinking if this query is posible. but I think its not.

```
SELECT

SUM(IF(designation   = "Senior%", 1,0)) AS `Senior_total`,
SUM(IF(designation   = "Junior%", 1,0)) AS `Junior_total`

From mytable
```

Comment: mby try to use designation LIKE ('Senior_')

Comment: Er, `SUM (designation LIKE 'senior%')` !!!

Answer (score 0):

The query is possible it is just you syntax that is wrong it should be:

```
SELECT

SUM(IF(designation   LIKE "Senior%", 1,0)) AS `Senior_total`,
SUM(IF(designation   LIKE "Junior%", 1,0)) AS `Junior_total`

From mytable
```